# ie7 inserts line break after / before form tag

Tags: html, forms, formatting

I'm sure someone has noticed this before but I can't seem to find a solution. In IE7 before and after form tags IE inserts line breaks. This is no good! Sample code below... Solutions? Ideas?

```
  <html>
    <body>
        <div id="pageContent" style="border:1px solid black; background-color:orange;">
        <form> 
        content bad <!-- notice spaces before and after form tags --> 
        </form> 
        </div>
        <div id="pageContent2" style="border:1px solid black; background-color:orange;">
        content good <!-- no spacing -->
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with a valid [doctype declaration](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html) above your `<html>` tag. Omitting this causes the browser to use [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) instead of standards mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

If that doesn't solve it, add a css rule to remove all margin and padding from form elements:

```
form { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Agreed, just set margin-top and margin-bottom for the form tag to 0.